# Compiling clang++ with -std=gnu++11 fails

Tags: c++11, clang, clang++

I am trying to compile my project via clang++, version 3.4. I am using flag -std=gnu++11, and it fails.

Earlier I used llvm 3.3 and everything was OK. but now i have such error message:

```
clang (LLVM option parsing): Unknown command line argument '-std=gnu++11'.  Try: 'clang (LLVM option parsing) -help'
clang (LLVM option parsing): Did you mean '-stats=gnu++11'?
```

Comment: try changing -std=gnu++11 to -std=c++11 instead. (hope everyone is happy...)

Comment: it is not the case. Problem was about key -std itself. I've tried every possible standart and problem still ocured

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testing shows that this error can come up when some other bogus options get used. For example:

```
$ clang -mllvm -std=gnu++11 test3.cc -o test3
clang (LLVM option parsing): Unknown command line argument '-std=gnu++11'.  Try: 'clang (LLVM option parsing) -help'
clang (LLVM option parsing): Did you mean '-stats=gnu++11'?
```

The `-mllvm` option tells clang to not process the `-std=gnu++11` option itself, but to pass it on to LLVM. But LLVM has no idea what this option means.

To solve the problem, make sure your other options are correct; the error message is leading you to think the problem is somewhere it isn't.